# How does mobile YouTube play videos?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm looking to add some videos to my mobile webapp. For the best UX, I'd like to avoid having a simple static video-tag. (because its in an element which is webkit animated and video + webkit animations don't always play nicely together in my experience.)

Rather, I'd like to have an image (with a play icon on it) to "link" to the video. [Mobile YouTube](http://m.youtube.com) (as seen on iOS) have done this very nicely where when you click the image, the video seems to "pop"  up to fullscreen and plays. How do they do this? Is it a link? A previously hidden video-tag? Some webkit-animation to do the "popping"?

I snooped around using Chrome Inspector (+user agent switcher to iphone4) but the videos don't play on the desktop browser, and the code overall looks quite complex..

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is on-click of the video thumbnail, you can load the video url using the object/embed tags. In IOS, whenever a video starts playing it automatically plays it in fullscreen(feature of IOS itself)

Comment: Actually a click on youtube link automatically opens app for youtube on iOS devices. Once I got to m.youyube.com instead of that and I consider the latter less convenient.

Comment: In the end I found how they do it, there's a tiny 2x1px video tag hidden in there which is played programmatically with an onClick thumbnail. As you said, the video pops out and plays in fullscreen automatically. Easy peasy..

Comment: wije care to give a bit more description about how you did this. I've just started trying to do the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something similar to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_full-screen_mode) on certain browsers (e.g. WebKit.)